# Does deleting CF's From the entire cassandra cluster will lead to Schema Disagreement Exception?

Tags: cassandra

I have a system where i deleted unwanted CF End of each day from cassandra cluster. Is this a bad practice? will that lead Schema Disagreement Exception?

I also need to know what kind of operations will lead to schema disagreement (or schema changes)

Is it create, alter, drop CFs/keyspaces?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Schema disagreement is not a problem starting with Cassandra 1.2.  If you are on an older release, you should upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to this

"If you make multiple changes at the same time, you can cause some nodes to end up with a different schema, than others."

So deleting might cause it however, is it a bad practice to delete CFs?

These are the operations that will cause schema changes

1. Add column family or keyspace
2. Drop column family or keyspace
3. Rename column family or keyspace